# Nuxt3: Why are selected radio buttons not shown when using in a layout component?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am using custom page layouts for my nuxt3 app. When user selects a radio option, the URL changes to reflect the change (ie, 'solved', 'unsolved' radio options). This works good, **however, the radio buttons are not shown for the checked item. For example, when user presses "solved tickets" radio option, the radio button is not shown for that item. What am I doing wrong?**

[image]

`components/AppFilter.vue`

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <div class="list-group">
      <NuxtLink to="/" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <input
          class="form-check-input me-1"
          type="radio"
          name="listGroupRadio"
          value="all"
          id="firstRadio"
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="firstRadio"
          >All tickets/index page</label
        >
      </NuxtLink>
      <NuxtLink to="/solved" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <input
          class="form-check-input me-1"
          type="radio"
          name="listGroupRadio"
          value="solved"
          id="secondRadio"
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="secondRadio">Solved Tickets</label>
      </NuxtLink>
      <NuxtLink to="/unsolved" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <input
          class="form-check-input me-1"
          type="radio"
          name="listGroupRadio"
          value="unsolved"
          id="thirdRadio"
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="thirdRadio"
          >Unsolved Tickets</label
        >
      </NuxtLink>
    </div>
    {{ picked }}
  </section>
</template>
```

Stackblitz reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-dmx5zu?file=components/AppFilter.vue

Answer (score 1):

Pretty funky structure IMO but that one works fine

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()

const picked = ref([])
const updateRadioAndMove = ({ radio, newPath }) => {
  picked.value = radio.target.value
  router.push(newPath)
}
</script>

<template>
  <section>
  <br/>
    picked radio button >> {{ picked }}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    
    <div class="list-group">
        <input
          @change="updateRadioAndMove({ radio: $event, newPath: '/' })"
          class="form-check-input me-1"
          type="radio"
          name="listGroupRadio"
          value="all"
          id="firstRadio"
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="firstRadio"
          >All tickets/index page</label
        >
        <input
          @change="updateRadioAndMove({ radio: $event, newPath: '/solved' })"
          class="form-check-input me-1"
          type="radio"
          name="listGroupRadio"
          value="solved"
          id="secondRadio"
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="secondRadio">Solved Tickets</label>
        <input
          @change="updateRadioAndMove({ radio: $event, newPath: 'unsolved' })"
          class="form-check-input me-1"
          type="radio"
          name="listGroupRadio"
          value="unsolved"
          id="thirdRadio"
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="thirdRadio"
          >Unsolved Tickets</label
        >
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks @kissu, that does seem like over kill. Is there not a better and more simpler way to achive my desired output? Maybe I am overthinking this layout thing.

Comment: @redshift I mean, I'm not sure why you want some checkboxes + page change. One seems enough to me (page change). But maybe it's required by your project? Just looks wrong from a design aspect to have something like that. But the given solution works fine if this is what you want to have in your project.

Comment: I am trying to achieve what nuxt modules website does with the sorting . When you click "nuxt 3" the page query is sent to URL address and the data is updated: https://modules.nuxtjs.org/?version=3.x

Comment: @redshift that one is a matter of [pushing a `query`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location) + [watching the `$route`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71685443/8816585).

Comment: I think I simplified it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-svj471?file=README.md . Now I just need to conver to radio buttons!

Comment: @redshift that one is also a better/simpler approach.